# Check user submitted password in database

Tags: python, django, forms, django-authentication

I'm new in Django programming and I'm stuck in this problem.
This is the code that I have in `views.py`:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
    else:
        context = RequestContext(request, {})
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

How can I search the user that have the email inserted in the html form, and check if the password is correct?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have a read through the [documentation on the authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) which has an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Most likely you can use some javascript to check the value you are entering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        # Assuming the fields in your `User` model are labeled the same
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    else:
        context = RequestContext(request, {})
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```